# Binaries outside of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to store the binary data outside the database and on a computer external to the SQL Server server? I am aware of FILESTREAM and FileTables but these store the files in the file system of the same SQL Server server and I need to be able to store them outside of this.

Comment: What is the *binary data* to which you refer? Is it the database itself, or the contents of a column in a table?

Comment: To text files, images, videos, etc. I want to be able to save them remotely, and check RBS, but it does not work for me because it is especially for SharePoint which is paid and I am asked to do it for free

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Remote Blob Store (RBS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/remote-blob-store-rbs-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15), or you can simply store a UNC path in SQL Server and store the files on a file share hosted on some other system.

Comment: I have researched RBS but I have only found this one that works with SharePoint, which has a cost, they ask me for a solution that is free of charge